# Removing Sub-string with some pattern from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, string

I have a string something like JSON format:

> XYZ DIV Parameters: width=\"1280\" height=\"720\", session=\"1\"

Now I want to remove `width=\"1280\" height=\"720\"` from this string.

**Note**: There can be any number in place of 1280 and 720. So, I can't just replace it with null.

Please tell me how to solve it? Either by Regex or any other better method possible.

Comment: Could you give us a more realistic example of your input string?

Comment: If one of the answers were helpful to you, make sure to approve it so others in the future can see which one was most helpful.  It gives the people who take time to answer a little more bonus for helping :)  Everyone loves fake internet points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex to be replaced with empty string:

```
(width|height)=\\"\d+\\"
```

Regex visualization:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Code:

```
string input = @"XYZ DIV Parameters: width=\""1280\"" height=\""720\"", session=\""1\""";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(width|height)=\\""\d+\\""", string.Empty);
```

Comment: +1, The way you handle the `width|height` part of the regex is so clean!  I didn't even think of that.  Bravo!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and intelligently achieved solution. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do a find and replace using the following regex:

`width=\\"\d*+\\"` replace with a blank string, as well as replacing `height=\\"\d*+\\"` with a blank string.

This is removing the entire text of `width=\"XYZ\"`, if you wanted to just replace the numbers or blank out the numbers you can replace with a string that suits your needs (`width=\"\"` for example)

If you can guarantee the width and height will ALWAYS be in that format and ALWAYS follow each other seperated by a space, you can combine that into one bigger regex find/replace using `width=\\"\d*+\\" height=\\"\d*+\\"`.

---

A little more explanation on the regex so you take something away, not just a quick fix :)
`width=\\"\d*+\\"` breaks down to:

1. `width=` pretty simple, just find the text you are looking for to start your removal.
2. `\\"` since `\` is a special char in regex you have to escape it, then the `"` char can just follow it up like normal.
3. `\d*+` digits `\d`, zero or more of them `*`, and then non greedy `+`.  The important part here is the non greedy on the digits.  If you left that off, your regex would look and consume digits until it found the last `"`.  Not 100% needed in your case (since height is buffering) but it is still a lot safer.
4. `\\"` to end the regex out

Comment: Thank you Walls for such a great info. I am actually marking @Ulugbek's answer as it gives the exact code to the point. But without your this info I can't understand it. I might have done more +1s if SO allowed on your answer :)

Comment: @Ulugbek's answer is probably the best one.  He provided some actual code you can use.  I went more for the theory and explanation.  I don't need the check, I just like making sure people are getting what they need and are learning.  I learned something from his answer too, so I approve :)

Comment: That's really great @Walls. SO has people like you who believe in giving and taking knowledge as much as possible, that's why it is the best knowledge sharing website. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^(.*?)width=\\"".*?\\"" height=\\"".*?\\""(.*?)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    resultString = regexObj.Replace(subjectString, @"$1width=\""\"" height=\""\""$2");
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```